# Copy assemblies to build directory using MSBuild task

Tags: msbuild

I'm new to MSBuild and was wondering how could you copy all files in your lib directory to your build directory? if you could point to some online resource that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a copy task.
Refer to this URL(definition and example): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

Comment: Is there anyway to refer to the build directory? build is automated on the server so I dont know the absolute path to the build directory

Comment: You can use MSBuild Property MSBuildProjectDirectory to get the project path and then navigate to bin\Debug or bin\Release depending on Configuration property.

Answer (score 0):

visual studio uses ItemGroup/Reference  and ItemGroup/Content for this

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="nunit.framework,...">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Content Include="TestData\nwind.mdb">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```